# How-to use a shared library in native-activity

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, native-activity

I have an Android project with a native activity.
This native activity uses a shared library named "main" (libmain.so file) for starting.
( with the code of ndk/samples/native-activity )

This app works fine.

the "main" module Android.mk file :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := main
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv1_CM

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue game

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

Now I want to add another shared library (for example a game engine) used by "main" library.
I have built a "game" module (libgame.so).

But when I link the "main" with the "game", like this :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := main
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../game

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv1_CM
LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libgame.so

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue game

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

with code no changes !
the app doesn't start anymore and I have this error in Logcat :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.myproject/android.app.NativeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native library: /data/data/com.mycompany.myproject/lib/libmain.so
```

This crash is due to adding link to a shared library ...

Why linking to a shared library make the app not loading (crash) ?
How can I use a shared library in a native android project (no-java / native-activity) ?
(I suppose it can be possible ... otherwise the native activity is quite limited ...)

Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must list all your shared libraries in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="game" />
<meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="main" />
```

Not sure about the order of libraries. Try change the order if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks ! But, are you sure ? Have you already tried this ? I have tried this and changing the order ... the problem is the same (crash) [http://pastie.org/3308037](http://pastie.org/3308037)

Comment: I am having the exact same issue as you.  This did not fix it.

Comment: Yes, my answer was incorrect. This considered as a bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28329 Simple workaround would be subclass NativeActivity with empty activity that has only System.loadLibrary() calls to load all needed libraries.

Comment: that does seem odd, since this does get past linking issues and can load the other libraries, but it doesn't seem to actually make it work.  Even though it's not a full solution, you get my upvote.