# how to unmake a makefile into gcc options?

Tags: android, linux, gcc, makefile

For reasons given at [Android gcc sysroot and linker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680791/android-gcc-sysroot-and-linker), I am compiling my Android NDK project with `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`.

This requires compiling the source, with the options specified in a makefile as for example given at

[How-to use a shared library in native-activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111107/how-to-use-a-shared-library-in-native-activity).

Is there any way to unmake, or in other words, reverse a gcc makefile into the equivalent command-line options?

e.g. how would you reverse `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue`

Comment: I'd do a dry run and look at the commands that would be executing if it was executing.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do?  What about `make -n`?

Comment: @CarlNorum I updated the post with an example of what exactly I'm make-unmake-ing. Does that help and can you answer the question now?

Comment: `make -n` as ?http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html?  what is that supposed to do?