# Using GNU STL and C++11 with V8 on Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, c++11, android-ndk, v8

I am building an application on Android using NDK and V8. I would prefer to use C++11 and GNU STL for features such as `shared_ptr`; however, the V8 build system seems to be hardcoded to use `stlport_static` as its STL variant.

Even when [patching the build system to generate a fully self-contained library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24296105/318857), V8's build does not statically link STLport into its .a files (which is to be expected), and thus I get hundreds of linker errors from unresolved symbols in `libv8_base.a` et al.  I also do not see any way to indicate to `ndk-build` that it should link in `stlport_static` when I am using a different STL variant.

Is there a reasonable pattern to linking in `stlport_static` while using `gnustl_static`, or, better yet, is there a way of building Android V8 against `gnustl_static` instead?

Comment: Does your native code talk to `libjv8.so` directly, or to its static libs? Or your Java loads the two independent shared libs?

Comment: My native code talks to `libv8_base.a`, and `libv8_base.a` depends on the `stlport_static` libraries. I could just use `stlport_static` myself but I *really* want `shared_ptr` and proper move semantics in my containers... In any case I am not building a `.so` of v8, as that doesn't seem to even be an option.

Comment: Now open in the AOSP bug tracker: [Issue 216331: STLport does not support C++11](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216331).

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem. Well, mixing different STLs in separate .so's is possible, with extra care; but using two STLs inside one .so is simply impossible.

You either need to implement your own `shared_ptr` (no big deal), but then you will face the same issue for every other feature that exists in *gnustl* and not in *stlport*.

Or you need to port V8 to *gnustl* (and I am afraid that the MIT license does not allow this).

Comment: It looks like gnustl and stlport both use different internal symbols for all of their implementation classes, though, so I don't see what makes mixing them within a .so impossible. But what in the MIT license and/or modified GPL prohibits V8 from linking in gnustl? Is this why V8 only supports stlport?  Anyway, it's looking like it'll be easier to just pull in `boost::shared_ptr` instead, which I was hoping to avoid but oh well.